Подключение метрик node_exporter
На оборудовании прикручен node_exporter, он работает корректно. Однако в ответе этого экспортера отсутствуют некоторые метрики, которые должны быть включены.
Как я могу узнать, они просто отключены или с ними что-то случилось?
И как включить их, если они отключены?

Прочитать документацию по соответствующим метрикам, наверное? А ещё есть метрика node_scrape_collector_success
